# Angular, filtering down a json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big json object I am using to control a cascading select list that I am trying to filter down to prepare for sending to the server.

The structure looks something like this -

```
      Accounts[{name:account1, id:1, selected:false, schools:[{name:school1, id:2,selected:true}]}]
```

(With multiple accounts with multiple schools in each, keeping it simple for example purposes)

What I am trying to do is put it through some maps/filters and achieve an array of ids of schools that have the key of selected = true. So my attempt is to filter down by first all schools, then by schools that have selected true, then just the id's of those schools.

So here is my attempt -

```
  $scope.schooIDsForSave =  $scope.accountTreeHere.filter( function(obj){
            return obj.schools;
        }).filter( function(obj){
            return obj.selected;
        }).map(function(obj){
            return obj.id;
        });
```

This is only returning 1 ID so I'm getting something wrong here. I think I have something wrong with my usage of map/filter as I am still vey new to it. Any insight to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given structure

```
var schools = [{
    name: 'account1',
    id: 1,
    selected: false,
    schools: [{
        name: 'school1',
        id: 2,
        selected: true
    }]
}, {
    name: 'account2',
    id: 2,
    selected: false,
    schools: [{
        name: 'school2',
        id: 3,
        selected: false
    }]
}];
```

Try

```
var ids = schools.map(function(v) {
    return v.schools;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}).filter(function(v) {
    return v.selected;
}).map(function(v) {
    return v.id;
});
```